# 'Wallet and Apple Pay' missing from Macbook Pro settings

Tags: macbook-pro, settings, apple-pay

I have macbook following version.

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014), OS: Mac OS Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88)

I am using the following link to setup Apple pay for Mac.

https://www.imore.com/how-set-and-manage-apple-pay-mac

But i can't see the option of 'Wallet and Apple Pay' in the System Preference.

Answer (score 5):

Only MacBook Pro with Touch ID have a ‘Wallet and Apple Pay’ preference pane, as these Macs are the only ones which have the necessary hardware support for storing cards for Apple Pay on device.

On older Macs, Apple Pay is still supported with a compatible iPhone. No configuration is available on the Mac, since the Mac delegates to the iPhone for Apple Pay.

To enable Apple Pay on your Mac using your iPhone, go to Settings → Wallet & Apple Pay and turn on ‘Allow Payments on Mac’.

Comment: My MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) has Touch ID, but does not have "Wallet & Apple Pay".